# How to change the name of the output text file automatically with textbox data in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Dim objWriter1 As System.IO.StreamWriter, objWriter2 As System.IO.StreamWriter

        objWriter1 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\first.txt", True)
        objWriter2 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\second.txt", True)
```

What I really want is to change the name of the text file to be saved as one of the Textbox data (Textbox1.Text) automatically

Can I do that ???

Comment: When would you want this to happen? (Question does not really make sense: just set the value of the text box to the same value you've passed to the `StreamWriter` constructor: I think you need to expand with additional context: why are you trying to do this?)

Comment: Suppose if I have "Stack" as data entered inside the Textbox1 and If I click on "Generate Text File" button, then i should have a text file with the name "Stack first.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Well I got figured it out myself

I used the following code

```
Dim objWriter1 As System.IO.StreamWriter, objWriter2 As System.IO.StreamWriter

        objWriter1 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\" + Textbox1.Text + "first.txt", True)
        objWriter2 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\" + Textbox1.Text + "second.txt", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objWriter1 As System.IO.StreamWriter, objWriter2 As System.IO.StreamWriter
   'Whatever the value is in textbox1, will be displayed as the name of the file
    objWriter1 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\" & textbox1.text & ".txt", True)
   'Whatever the value is in textbox2, will be displayed as the name of the file
    objWriter2 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\" & textbox2.text & ".txt", True)
```